# Symfony2 custom form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have form with checkboxes loaded from database (I use entity field type). Checkboxes are regions and districts. I have following database schema:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| id | parent_id | name             |
+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | NULL      | Region           |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2  | 1         | District         |
+-----------------------------------+
| 3  | 1         | Another district |
+-----------------------------------+
| 4  | NULL      | Another region   |
+-----------------------------------+
| 5  | 4         | Next district    |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Problem is that I need following form. How to do that?

```
<b>Region</b><!-- Loaded from database -->
<!-- Dictricts ordered by name -->
<input type="checkbox" id="someId" value="3"><label for="someId">Another district</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="someId" value="2"><label for="someId">District</label>
<b>Another region</b><!-- Loaded from database -->
<!-- Dictricts ordered by name -->
<input type="checkbox" id="someId" value="5"><label for="someId">Next district</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176223/1153358) I've solve this by custom rendering form template.

Answer (score 0):

EntityType field with options :

- multiple = true
- expanded = true
- property = 'name'
- class = 'YourBundle:YourEntity'
- query_builder = 'function (EntityRepository $er) {return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                     ->where('r.parentId  IS NOT NULL')
                     ->orderBy('r.parentId', 'ASC')->orderBy('r.name', 'ASC');}'

Comment: This will not help. Result will be sorted by `name` but I need result which will be grouped by **Region** and **Dictricts** in each region sorted by `name`.

Comment: Do you define a reflexive relation on your entity (on parentId) ? Anyway, you can't do that with the native query_builder brought with EntityType field. You'll have to define a reflexive relation, get your entities well-sorted with INDEX BY DQL query, and send the results in the *choices* option...

Comment: Can you explain what is _reflexive relation_?

Comment: In this case, your Territory Entity is related on itself through the parentId property. Something like that with Annotation mapping :  @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Territory") ;  @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id") on the parentId property. See http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional