# Symfony 2 Forms entity Field Type grouping

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm rendering a form in Symfony2 with data_class mapped to `Reservation` entity, and this form has a entity field type, of class `Service`. The relation between `Reservation` and `Service` class is many to many. A service then has a `ServiceType`, which is another class, that is mapped as many to one from the `Service` class

What I want to do is display all services as checkboxes in the reservation form, grouped by service type. So far, I can display all the services together like this (the code is from `ReservationType` class):

```
$builder->add('services','entity', array(
         'class' => 'MyBundle:Service',
         'multiple' => true,
         'expanded'  => true
 ));
```

And displaying the form the default way:

```
<form action="{{ path('reservations', {'step': 2}) }}" method="post" {{    form_enctype(form) }}>
   {{ form_widget(form) }}

   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The result is something like this:

```
 □ servicetype1 option
 □ servicetype1 another option
 □ servicetype2 option
 □ servicetype2 another option
```

What I would like to achieve is:

```
servicetype1:
  □ option
  □ another option
servicetype2:
  □ option
  □ another option
```

I was trying to specify only subsets of services by using query_builder option like this:

```
    $builder->add('services','entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyBundle:Service',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'query_builder' => function (\My\Bundle\Entity\ServiceRepository $repository)
                {return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')->where('s.serviceType = ?1')->setParameter(1, 1);} ));
    $builder->add('services','entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyBundle:Service',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'query_builder' => function (\My\Bundle\Entity\ServiceRepository $repository)
                {return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')->where('s.serviceType = ?1')->setParameter(1, 2);} ));
```

This is wrong, because:

1. I have to specify the `ServiceType` id
2. Adding the `'services'` to the builder twice, will overwrite the first addition (which is logical, but cannot be solved without changing the entities)

What would be the best option for handling forms like this? There are only 2 `ServiceType`-s so far, but I would like to keep it dynamic, and reusable.

Comment: I've got [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128223/symfony2-custom-form)

Comment: I have similar problem. This my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181738/symfony2-form-many-fields-for-the-same-property). When you will complete this task, you write some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by using the [group_by option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by):

```
$builder->add('services','entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Service',
    'group_by' => 'serviceType',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded'  => true
));
```

Comment: Great, good to see they added this option. Re-accepting this as it's much simpler.

Comment: It's not working in this case – with option `expanded => true`. In documentation is stated: “It only works when rendered as a select tag”.

Answer (score 9):

I suppose the only way to do that is override rendering in the template. You should pass to your template entity `MyBundle:Service` and render it for example like this:

```
{% for service in services %}    
    <b>{{ service.name }}</b><br>
    {% for option in service.options %}                    
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="form_type_name[options][{{ option.id }}]" value="{{ option.id }}" {% if option in user.services.options %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
            {{ option.name }}
        </label>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, you mean like passing it from controller to the template, avoiding using FormType for this part of the form? Doesn't this kill the re-usability a little?

Comment: Ended up using this solution anyway. Thanks/Díky :)