# How to render a multiple choice dropdown with option groups using "sonata_type_model" or symfony "entity"?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to render a multiple choice selection drop-down similar to [the SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9175593/1179841) using `sonata_type_model` or `entity` type. I have the entity `Property` with `manyToMany` to `Feature` that is `oneToMany` of `FeatureType`. The multi-choice drop-down is being implemented in the Property create form.

I have found [the group_by option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by). But I got the warning using `entity` and got the incorrect rendering using `sonata_type_model`.

### Attempt 1

```
->add('features', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Feature',
    'multiple' => true,
    'group_by' => 'featureType'
))
```

> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/Factory/DefaultChoiceListFactory.php at line 334

### Attempt 2

```
->add('features', 'sonata_type_model', array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'btn_add' => null,
    'group_by' => 'featureType'
))
```

It only renders the values in the drop-down such as

[image]

### Attempt 3

I tried the `choices` and but got error

```
->add('features', 'sonata_type_model', array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'btn_add' => null,
    'choices' => $this->getFeatureOptionsWithGroup()
))
```

> Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Util/ClassUtils.php at line 58

### Attempt 4

I tried the `choice_list` and but got error

```
->add('features', 'sonata_type_model', array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'btn_add' => null,
    'choice_list' => $this->getFeatureOptionsWithGroup()
))
```

> The option "choice_list" with value array is expected to be of type "null" or "Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface", but is of type "array" in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.php at line 888

The method `getFeatureOptionsWithGroup()` returns the array like this

```
array(
    'Group 1' => array(
        1 => 'Feature 1'
        2 => 'Feature 2'
    ),
    'Group 2' => array(
        3 => 'Feature 3'
        4 => 'Feature 4'
    )
)
```

### Attempt 5

I updated the method using `ModelChoiceList`, but got the same error of using `choices`.

> Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Util/ClassUtils.php at line 58

```
private function getFeatureOptionsWithGroup()
{
    return new ModelChoiceList(
        $this->modelManager,
        'MyBundle:Feature',
        null,
        null,
        $this->getRepository('MyBundle:Feature')->getFeatureOptionsWithGroup()
    );
}
```

I hope that I would have a chance to render it without template override. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the type `entity`

```
->add('features', 'entity', [
       'class'     => 'MyBundle:Feature',
       'property'  => 'name',
       'choices'   => $this->getFeatureOptionsWithGroup(),
       'multiple'  => true,
       'required'  => false,
       'btn_add'   => null,
])
```

Make sure your function `getFeatureOptionsWithGroup()` returns like this

```
array(
       'Group 1' => array(
           1 => 'Feature Entity Object 1',
           2 => 'Feature Entity Object 2',
       ),
       'Group 2' => array(
           3 => 'Feature Entity Object 3',
           4 => 'Feature Entity Object 4',
       )
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use `group_by` option.

So on your case, you need to pass name of `$property` field in your `FeatureType` entity then on your Property entity, you need to implement `__toString()` function which should be the name of the Property as string.

**Explanation**:

On your `FeatureType` entity table, Property association is mapped by `property_id` as foreign key and Doctrine does the querying for you so you just need to specify how you want to group them.