# In Symfony EntityType fields, how do you change the rendered OPTGROUP text?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

Symfony has an *EntityType* field that allows a `<select>` field to be automatically populated by rows in a table. Going further, these rows can be categorized into `<optgroup>` clusters if the *group_by* option is given a property path.

**Example:**

```
$builder->add('categories', EntityType::class, [
        'class'        => PostCategory::class,
        'group_by'     => 'column_name',
        'mapped'       => FALSE,
    ]);
```

Given this code snippet, how would I change the rendered `<optgroup>` text? For example, how would I humanize (e.g. capitalize) it?

Comment: Probably not the simple answer you are looking for, but you could always do a custom rendering of your form. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176223/546262) for an example.